# Owned form and mdi parent

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

this is my scenario and hope you can solve it for me

I have a MDI container form called "MainForm". In MainForm there is a simple form call "Form1". In Form1 there is a button. every time you pushed it, It open a new form which instance of  "Form2". The followng code is click button event.

```
Button_Click()
{
   Form2 frm=new Form2();
   frm.mdiparnt=this.MdiParent;
   this.addOwnedForm(frm);
   frm.Visible=true;
}
```

and the following code tries to close owned forms when the user close Form1

```
Form1_CloseEvent()
{
   foreach(var item in this.ownedForm)
   {
      item.close();
   }
}
```

But when the debugger steps into close event, just close Form1, and the form2 instances remain open. what should I do to solve it

Comment: Where does `Form1_CloseEvent()` method exists?

Comment: Form2 cannot be both an MdiChild and have Form1 as an owner, since MainForm is already the owner.  How does that code even run without getting an exeception?...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not setting up the event. Do it like this.

Add it to your `Button_Click()` method:

```
this.FormClosed += Form1_FormClosed;
```

Here is the method:

```
void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var item in this.ownedForm)
    {
        item.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all this code does not compile!

you have several syntax errors: `mdiparnt`, `addOwnedForm`, `ownedForm`, `close`

you are probably not sharing your actual code and that's gonna be a problem to help you if it's not your code.

now in `Button_Click()` event you are doing

```
frm.mdiparnt=this.MdiParent;
this.AddOwnedForm(frm);
```

even though you only need

```
this.AddOwnedForm(frm);
```

or an exception will be thrown. i've checked this code and it's working just fine